# java applet doesn't work on my html page

Tags: java, html, applet

i am learning java at this moment and i've read somewhere that i can also run my java codes in a browser with an applet. if i try to use it, it says error click here for details.
the problem is that the java program does work in command prompt but not in the browser.
here is my HTML code. (Planet.class and the html file are both on my desktop)

```
<applet code="Planet.class" width=500 height=500 />
```

this is my java code (this code works nice in command prompt; don't try to get what it's exactly doing it just makes a rhombus out of *'s.) :

```
class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int n=20;
  int i;
  int k;
  int j;
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    for (k=n-i;k>=0;k--)
    { System.out.printf(" ");}
        for (j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)       
        {System.out.printf("*");}
        System.out.printf("\n");
  }

  for(i=n-1;i>=1;i--)
  {
    for (k=0;k<(n-i)+1;k++)
    { System.out.printf(" ");}
    for(j=2*i-1;j>=1;j--)      
         {System.out.printf("*");}
         System.out.printf("\n");
   } 
  }
}
```

i believe that it is just because the printf isn't supported in the browser but maybe i'm doing something else totally wrong please tell me.

Comment: please read [Lesson: Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)

Comment: You really need to learn how to correctly name variables...

Comment: i copied a code from somewhere once and that one did work

Comment: those are all just loop variables. giving them a name just makes it harder for me

Comment: Trying to code this without reading the tutorials first is like trying to drive a motorcycle blind. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @jannesbraet: sorry, but that's just plain foolish. You can't make up code and expect it to run. Be smart. Just RTFT.

Comment: it was just such a big load of information i just wanted to try out some things. it will at least take a week to read through all that if you haven't tryed something out by then, then you're not doing good i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is not an applet. For this class to be an applet it would have to inherrit either `Applet` or `JApplet`.
2. Applets don't use main method (they have other lifecycle methods)
3. You were right --- system out does not end in a webpage but in java console.

Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your class must extend JApplet. If you use NetBeans, you will get some generated code and you can start learning from there.